# Why doesn't the current stop in neon lamps when all the atoms have been ionized?

Tags: spectroscopy

My personal experience (which could be wrong) tells me neon lamps can theoretically run on forever or at least a very long time. If current is the flow of charge why doesn't it stop once all the atoms have been ionized? Do these atoms they continuously loose and gain electrons? If so why then doesn't the light concentrate to the side of the cathode were all the ions attract to?[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, the neon atoms lose then gain electrons.

Comment: Hint: The light does not come from *ionization*, but from *recombination*.

Comment: It is worth noting that, even if the ions concentrated at one electrode, most lamps are not DC they are AC so the process would be reversed 50 or 60 times per second. But that isn't what is happening anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If current is the flow of charge why doesn't it stop once all the atoms have been ionized?

The short answer is that it is impossible to ionize all the gas at once. It just requires huge amount of energy to ionize the whole atoms at once. Just for the sake of discussion, even at 10000 °C, still a very small fraction of atoms is ionized! This temperature is hotter than the surface of the Sun! A neon discharge tube is not even close to those temperatures or let us say energies.

The red glow of neon tubes you see is mainly due to electronically excited neon *atoms*. The pressure of the gas is pretty low inside the tube. Once you start applying a voltage, electrons emit from the cathode and ionize the gas forming a a number neon ions. These ions and free electrons are responsible for carrying the current. Since you are constantly supplying current, it continues to flow through the discharge tube and the process of ionization and recombination continues. Remember that ionization is an equilibrium process in the gas phase as well. An additional process can also occur, that the electron is promoted to a higher energy orbital instead of leaving the atom. Once it jumps back to its original orbit, it emits its characteristic wavelength of light.

I think the *recombination process stated above should yield a continuous spectrum so the red characteristic glow of neon tubes is not from recombination process*.

Answer (score 2):

Why is the current flowing through the discharge pipes and why does the ionization process not automatically stop as long as the required charges are available ?

The answer to this question lies in what is known as belt theory or transition bands. This theory has been developed to explain the material's ability to conduct conductivity in metallic materials as well as semiconductors and insulating materials.

This theory assumes that what is known as the free electrons that are responsible for our conventional electrical conduction are originally equal electrons - the electrons that the metal prepares to lose in return for its arrival at conventional chemical stability - and these electrons can not move from their level as simply as they need energy. It can get out of those levels ....... In the case of metals, the required energy is limited and small amount and that is why some heating enough even the usual temperature of the atmosphere to provide these electrons some energy to move from the levels of corn to become Some metals, such as cesium and potassium, have energy at lower levels, such as light energy, until these electrons are released. The energy of the electric field can move these electrons, so it is easier for metals to transport electrons  once a difference is made Effort on both ends of the metal piece.

If the natural region of the valence electrons is located in a layer within the atom, the conduction electrons that have acquired energy are slightly higher than the valence electrons because of this energy. Therefore, the valence electrons region is said to almost interfere with the conductivity of the metals Ready to connect with the energy you gain from its surroundings and light.

In the case of insulating materials there exists what can be called a similar equivalence of electrons, but they are strongly related to the atoms or particles in the insulating material. In order to make the conductivity possible, these electrons must be lifted to the free zone or the conductivity range. In this case, the beam theory states that the difference in energy Between the two bands is large and therefore there must be a vacuum or a large gap between the range of equivalence and the range of conductivity so the insulation can not easily connect the electricity and requires a lot of energy to make them do so and can be provided through extreme heating, for example, It is known that each material dielectric breakdown voltage electrical own.

In the case of semiconductors, the difference in energy or gap between the valence and conductivity ranges is limited and small. Therefore, modest energy is required to move to the conductivity state - for example, a pure silicon plate that can not easily plug in the current but some heating is sufficient to do so.
In the case of gaseous materials such as in the discharge pipes, we put a very high voltage on the gas to make it move from the state of isolation to the state of conductivity and the electric field to make energy on the electrons to transfer them to the delivery area beyond the gap, and once this happens, atoms break into an active mixture Of the ions with the electrons and with the stability of the dissociation power or the difference in voltage, they remain unchanged without ever equalizing because the energy allowed to bypass the conduction gap and forced the atoms to disintegrate but once the source of the voltage is removed the electrons return to the equivalence level and lose their energy in the form of light Equalized atoms to return to the buffer status.

If the plasma mixture inside the tubes can not be automatically drawn unless the source of the electrical voltage or the ionizing heat is removed.

Comment: How does the light come?